# Undeclared Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure something is wrong with my function declaration

```
$(window).ready(function(){

if isScrolledIntoView(".my_class"){
    $("#some_id").hide();
}

});


function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to wrap `()` around if condition also use `window.load` or `document.ready`.

```
$(window).load(function(){

if (isScrolledIntoView(".my_class")){
    $("#some_id").hide();
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isScrolledIntoView(".my_class")){
```